# Power hungry google foobar challenge fails 4th test case

Tags: java, arrays

I have submitted the test already so this isn't violation of Stack Overflow guidelines.
I have been trying to solve this google foobar question **Power Hungry** which reads as:

> Commander Lambda's space station is HUGE. And huge space stations take a LOT of power. Huge space stations with doomsday devices take even more power. To help meet the station's power needs, Commander Lambda has installed solar panels on the station's outer surface. But the station sits in the middle of a quasar quantum flux field, which wreaks havoc on the solar panels. You and your team of henchmen have been assigned to repair the solar panels, but you'd rather not take down all of the panels at once if you can help it, since they do help power the space station and all!

> You need to figure out which sets of panels in any given array you can take offline to repair while still maintaining the maximum amount of power output per array, and to do THAT, you'll first need to figure out what the maximum output of each array actually is. Write a function solution(xs) that takes a list of integers representing the power output levels of each panel in an array, and returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers. So for example, if an array contained panels with power output levels of [2, -3, 1, 0, -5], then the maximum product would be found by taking the subset: xs[0] = 2, xs[1] = -3, xs[4] = -5, giving the product 2*(-3)*(-5) = 30.  So solution([2,-3,1,0,-5]) will be "30".

> Each array of solar panels contains at least 1 and no more than 50 panels, and each panel will have a power output level whose absolute value is no greater than 1000 (some panels are malfunctioning so badly that they're draining energy, but you know a trick with the panels' wave stabilizer that lets you combine two negative-output panels to produce the positive output of the multiple of their power values). The final products may be very large, so give the solution as a string representation of the number.

## Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution([2, 0, 2, 2, 0])
Output:
8

Input:
solution.solution([-2, -3, 4, -5])
Output:
60

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution({2, 0, 2, 2, 0})
Output:
8

Input:
Solution.solution({-2, -3, 4, -5})
Output:
60

---

I wrote the below code in Java

```java
public static String solution(int[] xs) {
    // Your code here
    // for(int i:xs)System.out.println(i);
    int n=xs.length;
    if(n==1){
        return String.valueOf(xs[0]);
    }
    int neg=0,z=0,ans=1,m_neg=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i:xs){
        if(i<0){
            neg++;
            m_neg=m_neg>i?m_neg:i;
        }
    }
    for(int i:xs){
        if(i==0){
            z++;
            continue;
        }
        if(neg%2==1 && i==m_neg){
            ans*=1;
        }
        else{
            ans*=i;
        }
    }
    if(z==n) return "0";

    if(neg%2==1){
        if(neg==1 && z>0 && z+neg==n) return "0";
    }
    return ans>0?String.valueOf(ans):"0";
}
```

One of the test cases (4th one to be precise) is failing. I tried various edge cases but I can't pass that.
Can anyone explain what did I miss?

Comment: Your code is producing `60` for `Solution.solution({-2, -3, 4, -5})`. So which test case is failing?

Comment: There are answers available to this  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237472

Comment: @onkarruikar the hidden test case (4th one) is failing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with single loop:

- Iterate over the array
- Keep multiplying with non zero elements
- Keep tracking the smallest value negative integer at the same time.
- If at the end product is negative then divide by the small value integer.

Like this:

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int[] arr = {-2, -3, 4, -5};
            System.out.println(solution(arr));
        }

    public static String solution(int[] xs) {
        BigInteger ans = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
            int j = xs[i];
            if(j>0) 
                ans = ans.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
            else if(j<0) {
                if(min<j) min = j;
                ans = ans.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(j));
            }
        }
        
        if(ans.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)<0) {
            ans = ans.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(min));
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
60
```

Note: this is just a demo. Fix or improve the code as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

My algorithm is as follows:

1. Sort the array.
2. Count the number of negative integers in the array.
3. If there is an odd number of negative integers in the array, save the index of the largest negative number. (In the array `{-2, -3, 4, -5}` the largest negative integer is `-2`.)
4. Iterate the array and multiply all the elements together, skipping elements that are 0 (zero) and skipping the largest negative integer (only if there are an odd number of negative integers in the array).

```java
/*
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
 */
public static String solution(int[] xs) {
    String result = "0";
    if (xs != null  &&  xs.length > 0) {
        if (xs.length == 1  &&  xs[0] <= 0) {
            return result;
        }
        Arrays.sort(xs);
        int i = 0;
        while (xs[i++] < 0) {
        }
        if (--i % 2 == 1) {
            --i;
        }
        else {
            i = -1;
        }
        BigInteger product = new BigInteger("1");
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < xs.length; j++) {
            if (xs[j] != 0  &&  j != i) {
                count++;
                product = product.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(xs[j])));
            }
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            result = product.toString();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I use `BigInteger` to store the result since, as stated in the question, the result may be very large.

Comment: it is mentioned that there can't be more than 50 cells and the maximum absolute value is 1000. so the maximum absolute power can't be greater than 50000 which comes under int

Comment: @PavanGuguloth 50 cells with maximum 1000 will be 50000 if we were to add them up. We have to multiply them. Which means 50^1000